# How to get an array all permutation in Actionscript 3.0?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, multidimensional-array, actionscript, permutation

Suppose I have an array A = [0,1,2]. How do I get the 2 dimensional array perm_A = [[0,1,2],[0,2,1][1,0,2][1,2,0][2,1,0],[2,0,1]? The order of which the permutation appper in perm_A does not matter.

I used the code in [Heap's Algoritm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm).

```
function generatePermute(k:int, arr:Array){
        if (k == 1){
        perm_list.push(arr);
    }
    else {
        generatePermute(k-1,arr);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < k-1; i++){
        if (k % 2 == 0){
            swap_arr(arr, i, k-1);
        }
        else{
            swap_arr(arr, 0, k-1);
        }
        generatePermute(k-1,arr);
    }
}

function swap_arr(input, index_A, index_B) {
    var temp = input[index_A];
 
    input[index_A] = input[index_B];
    input[index_B] = temp;
}

var arr:Array = [0,1,2, 3]
var perm_list:Array = new Array();
generatePermute(4,arr);
for (var i = 0; i<perm_list.length;i++){
    trace(perm_list[i])
}
```

The result is :

```
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
1,2,3,0
```

which is clearly wrong.

### update

if I change perm_list.push(arr); to trace (arr), I do get correct result. However, this only ouputs all the permutations in the console. I want to collect all of these permutations into a 2 dimensional array.

```
function generatePermute(k:int, arr:Array){
    if (k == 1){
        trace(arr)
    }
    else {
        generatePermute(k-1,arr);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < k-1; i++){
        if (k % 2 == 0){
            swap_arr(arr, i, k-1);
        }
        else{
            swap_arr(arr, 0, k-1);
        }
        generatePermute(k-1,arr);
    }
}

function swap_arr(input, index_A, index_B) {
    var temp = input[index_A];
 
    input[index_A] = input[index_B];
    input[index_B] = temp;
}

var arr:Array = [0,1,2, 3]
var perm_list:Array = new Array();
generatePermute(4,arr);
```

which outputs

```
0,1,2,3
1,0,2,3
2,0,1,3
0,2,1,3
1,2,0,3
2,1,0,3
3,1,0,2
1,3,0,2
0,3,1,2
3,0,1,2
1,0,3,2
0,1,3,2
0,2,3,1
2,0,3,1
3,0,2,1
0,3,2,1
2,3,0,1
3,2,0,1
3,2,1,0
2,3,1,0
1,3,2,0
3,1,2,0
2,1,3,0
1,2,3,0
```

My guess is it seems there is something wrong with perm_list.push(arr)

Comment: Probably **if (k % 2 == 0)** should be **if (i % 2 == 0)**.

Comment: Also, did you try to search for a ready solution? I googled **as3 permutations** and one of the first results was https://github.com/NicolasSiver/as3-nslibrary/blob/master/src/im/siver/library/math/Combinations.as

Comment: @Organis I've updated the question with possible solution. Kindly take a look...

Comment: I advise to name function argument **arr** differently from outside **arr** variable. That way you will be at least sure you are addressing the correct data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found what your actual mistake is. You fill the result **Array** with the references to **arr**, so in the end the result looks like **[arr, arr, arr, arr, arr ... arr]**. You don't put a current copy there, you put a reference to your actual object you are working on and you change the same object afterwards. The key is to copy the current state of your **arr** into the separate object.

```
var A:Array = new Array;

permutations([1, 2, 3, 0], 0, A);

trace(A.join("\n"));

function permutations(values:Array, index:uint, result:Array):void
{
    var i:uint;
    var len:uint = values.length;

    if (index == len)
    {
        // Look at the ".slice()" here, it is why
        // this one is working as expected.
        result.push(values.slice());
        return;
    }

    for (i = index; i < len; i++)
    {
        swap(values, index, i);
        permutations(values, index + 1, result);
        swap(values, index, i);
    }
}

function swap(list:Array, from:uint, to:uint):void
{
    var temp:* = list[from];
    list[from] = list[to];
    list[to] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What does the index argument in permutations() mean? Why you pass 0 for it in permutations([1, 2, 3, 0], 0, A); ?

Comment: It's the same as **k** of yours, the only difference is that you count down from 4 to 1, while this one counts up from 0 to 3.